# Why can't debug angular tests via --code-coverage flag

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, karma-coverage

I'm trying to debug a test method in angular/karma.
When I start my tests with `ng test` I can use breakpoints and debugger key.

But when I use `--code-coverage` flag, debugger key doesn't work and I can't put any breakpoint on browser. (I also try it in a new generated project).
It doesn't prevent my work, but I'm curious about this.

Comment: I'm able to run the debugger and using the `--code-coverage` flag. Could you provide more details (karma configuration and version)?

Comment: I'm trying it in cli generated project, nothing more... I think this is a known issue. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19084